# WPA_Supplicant disconnects on exit

Tags: freebsd, wpa-supplicant

I can't exit wpa supplicant and keep connected.

I tried using `&` and `-B` (individually). I'm using ARM FreeBSD on a Rasp Pi.

To clarify <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> is the only way I can exit, but upon doing so I disconnect from Wi-Fi. So in short, how do I resume to terminal and stay connected.

Comment: Is there a reason why you start wpa_supplicant manually and don't use the rc-script `/etc/rc.d/wpa_supplicant`?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean. I simply type wpa_supplicant -Dbsd -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf .

Comment: And why not `/etc/rc.d/wpa_supplicant onestart` (for example)?

Comment: Can u explain what it does please? I tried it and nothing happend. No error so it is definetly a command

Comment: Its fine. I rebooted to discover that the interface is now associated and i managed to install pkg. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for wasting people's time. I literally just installed FreeBSD. If anyone has the same problem here is the solution provided by Martin Sugioarto.
Just run:

```
/etc/rc.d/wpa_supplicant onestart
```

And then

```
reboot
```

If anyone has a better answer i'd be more than happy to accept it.

Sorry made a mistake :P

I changed my `/etc/rc.conf` file here is what I added:

```
ifconfig_wlan0="WPA DHCP"
```

Make sure to add this in before executing the above, yet again still new to BSD

Useful link: https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/network-wireless.html

Ps: Thanks martin!

Comment: `onestart` just starts for the current session. If it still works after a reboot, it means you have added something like `ifconfig_wlan0="WPA ..."` to your `/etc/rc.conf`. [The FreeBSD Handbook chapter](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/network-wireless.html) explains how to setup wifi.